# No volume icon in Rhythmbox

Tags: sound, icons, 17.10, rhythmbox

When I installed Ubuntu 17.10, I noticed that the volume icon in Rhythmbox was gone:

[image: My Rhythmbox]

But then I found this picture while wandering on the internet and I thought that maybe I'm the only one who has this problem since no one had brought it up.

So I just removed `rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar` as a workaround solution.

[image: Rhythmbox image from somewhere on the internet]

But yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 17.10 for my friend and he had the exact same problem as I did.

So, is there any way for me to retrieve the missing volume icon?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Please use the `ubuntu-bug` application to file a bug report. Be sure to add enough detail so the developers can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I summited a bug report already. But I don't think there's any detail to add. As I said, I installed ubuntu for my friend yesterday, so it is a newly installed with no configure being made.

Answer (score 36):

Oh, well, I found the answer myself. It's not a bug, just go into **plugin** -> **alternative toolbar setting**, there's un option to turn on volume icon.

Comment: This was such a waste of time, why author decided to remove volume control and put it into options? So stupid. +1

Comment: True that @Marecky

Answer (score 2):

**Menu** -> **Preferences** -> **Plugin**, where you can click and highlight **alternative toolbar**. Now that it is highlighted, at the bottom right there is another **Preference**, within which you can turn on Volume Control among other things.

When I used your method, the Playback control became weird (I couldn't find how to loop one song).